# Passing Arguments to an ASP .NET Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, arguments

So I've recently started working with ASP .NET but I am very familiar with other .NET frameworks. The application I'm working on needs to take in an string index as a command line-style argument. Right now in my Page class I have a const string that I'm using as a placeholder. So the question I have is a two parter:

1- How do I set up my applications innerts to recieve an argument that is passed in when the page is opened?

2- How do I pass that argument in to the page (especially while I'm working in VS 2010)?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pass arguments to web pages with request variables (ever hear of POST or GET?). The simplest way is to append the variables to the end of the url like this:

`http://localhost/Default.aspx?varname=varvalue&othervarname=othervarvalue`

In your codebehind, you can access the request variables with `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Like I said I'm new to web dev so I didn't know it worked that way. Much appreciated! For all who see this, this worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For #2:  In your project config on VS2010, to to the 'Web' tab and set the option to specific page with the desired URL:  `http://localhost/Default.aspx?varname=varvalue&othervarname=othervarvalue`