# Passing parameters ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there any way that I can pass parameters to a user control/page through the path(URL) in a ASP.Net Web application(not MVC).

i.e.
http://abc.com/news/para-1/para-2
where `para-1` and `para-2` are parameters.

Comment: Why the close vote? The question is quite clear.

Comment: Which ASP.NET version? Routing is supported much better in V4+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659199/passing-arguments-to-an-asp-net-page

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called `Routing`.

If you're using .NET 4+, you can read how to implement it in a Web Forms application on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Your rule essentially comes down to this, assuming `news.aspx` is where you want to go:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("NewsRoute",
    "News/{arg1}/{arg2}",
    "~/news.aspx");
```

You can then proceed to access the values using any of the following methods:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["arg1"]
<asp:Literal ID="Literal" Text="<%$RouteValue:arg1%>" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

If you're not using .NET 4+, Scott Hanselman writes about [ASP.NET FriendlyUrls](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx), which is available in NuGet.

Comment: Apparently this does not work with User controls? is there anyway I can get this work on user controls

Comment: You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData` to get the route data from anywhere within your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ASP.NET Friendly URLs](http://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com/)

> The ASP.NET Friendly URLs library makes it easy to enable
>   extensionless URLs for file-based handlers (e.g. ASPX, ASHX) in
>   ASP.NET applications.

There is a good introduction by Scott Hanselman: [Introducing ASP.NET FriendlyUrls - cleaner URLs, easier Routing, and Mobile Views for ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [QueryStrings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString).

Redirect your page like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?Name=" +
this.txtName.Text + "&LastName=" +
this.txtLastName.Text);
```

And on your new page get the values like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
    this.txtBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["LastName"];
}
```