# How to run an ASP.NET-Page with different data?

Tags: asp.net

On my ASP.NET-Core Webpage, I have a table where each row represents an object.
The objects are loaded from a database.
When I click on a row, I always want to be redirected to the same page, but I want the page to know which object was clicked on.
So I have to pass an identification parameter to the linking ASP page.
This must work somehow...
btw:

All my classes know my singleton called Controller, through which the pages can exchange data.

After six unsuccessful hours I would be very happy for help

Here is my Table:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Number
    </th>
    <th>
        Type
    </th>
    <th>
        State
    </th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        ZSBNumber

    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var Object in Model.getAll())
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Object.Seriennummer</td>
        <td>@Object.Type</td>
        <td>@Object.State</td>
        <td>@Object.Project</td>
        <td>@Object.ZSBNumber</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that you've tried so far

Comment: I've tried to use the <tr> element as a button, or add the class="page-link" and i tried the oneclick-bootsrap, but i have to call a funktion with the ID so the called funktion knows wich object was clicked, but nothing works...
So I deleted this tries ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this I would use a link

```
<a asp-action="{your-action}" 
asp-controller="{Your-Controller}" 
asp-route-Seriennummer="@Object.Seriennummer"
asp-route-ZSBNumber="@Object.ZSBNumber"
>
@Object.Seriennummer
</a>
```

Controller Action has function like this

```
public IAction Your-Action(string Seriennummer, string ZSBNumber){
  logic here
}
```

here is a source
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: My Webpage is not an ASP.NET-MVC - Project, I only use ASP.NET...
Is this only possible with the MVC-Framework?

Comment: Oh, sorry I guess you saying controller confused me. Have you tried the answers at this link?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336884/passing-parameters-asp-net